# Basis of Infinite dimensional Hilbert Space with a certain property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was thinking about a question that I saw here on the stackexchange and the following problem that stumped me crossed my mind: Suppose $H$ is an infinite dimensional, separable, Hilbert space, and $y\in H$ is nonzero. Does there exist an orthonormal basis $u_i$ of $H$ so that $\langle y,u_i \rangle \ne 0$ for all $i\ge1$? It seems to me the answer is yes, but I'm not sure why. It seems you can start with some arbitrary basis, and then "change basis" so that this property is satisfied, but the details escape me.

Comment: You don't care about orthogonality? In that case can't you just take $\{y, y+z_1,y+z_2,...\}$ where the $z_i$ are a basis for the orthogonal complement to $y$?

Comment: @Timkinsella, yes I do want the basis $u_i$ to be orthonormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Here is  a hint:  Given any $z$ in $H$ in $H$ with $\|y||=\|z\|$ there exists an isometric isomorphism $T$ of $H$ onto itself such that $Ty=z$.  Let $z=\sum a_iu_i$ with $a_i >0$ for all $i$ and $\|z\|=\|y\|$. Let $T$ be an isometric isomorphism $T$ of $H$ onto itself such that $Ty=z$. Let $v_i=T^{*}u_i$. This has the desired properties since $ \langle y,  T^{*}u_i\rangle= \langle Ty, u_i \rangle=\langle z, u_i \rangle>0$.

Proof of the first statement: There exists an orthonormal basis  $(w_i)$ with $w_1=\frac y {\|y\|}$. [Use Gram-Schmidt]. Similarly, there exists an orthonormal basis  $(v_i)$ with $v_1=\frac z {\|z\|}$. Now $T(\sum a_i w_i)=\sum a_i v_i$ defines an isometric isomorphism with $T(w_1)=v_1$ which is same as $Ty=z$ since $\|y||=\|z\|$.

Comment: I'm very excited to get a response from the legend @Kavi Rama Murthy. This solution makes sense to me, but how do we know such an isometric isomorphism exists?

Comment: @LostStatistician18 I have added some details. I hope it is clear now.